# How to peek 2d array with Haskell inline-c

Tags: arrays, c, haskell, multidimensional-array

Hello I'd like to work with `2d arrays`:

```
--2d arrays
cArray :: IO (Ptr (Ptr CDouble))
cArray = do
  x <- [C.block| double (*)[2] {

  double (*ptd)[2] = malloc(sizeof(double[2][2]));
  ptd[0][0] = 1.78;
  ptd[0][1] = 1.68;
  ptd[1][0] = 1.58;
  ptd[1][1] = 1.48;
  printf("the firstelement is: %f\n", ptd[1][1]);
  return ptd;
}|]
  
  return x
```

Then in another function:

```
  e <- cArray :: IO (Ptr (Ptr CDouble))
  e1 <- peekElemOff e 0 :: IO (Ptr CDouble)  
  e2 <- peekElemOff e1 0 :: IO CDouble
  print e2
```

This always gives segment fault.

For 1-d array, i don't have problems.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A C 2D array is really just a 1D array where, within its scope, the compiler keeps track of the row length to compute the 2D indexing. This size information would be lost if you transform to `Ptr (Ptr CDouble)`. A C 2D array is distinct from an array-of-arrays 2D array – which would in general be a *jagged array*, but you can also obtain such an array more efficiently with only two allocations – one for the content, one for the pointers to each row.

```
cArray :: IO (Ptr (Ptr CDouble))
cArray = [C.block| double** {

  int n = 2, m = 2;
  double* arr = malloc(sizeof(double[n*m]));
  double** ptd = malloc(sizeof(double*[n]));
  for (int i=0; i<2; ++i)
    ptd[i] = &(arr[i*m]);
  ptd[0][0] = 1.78;
  ptd[0][1] = 1.68;
  ptd[1][0] = 1.58;
  ptd[1][1] = 1.48;
  printf("the firstelement is: %f\n", ptd[0][0]);
  return ptd;
}|]
```

---

As you've remembered yourself, C-allocated memory eventually needs to be cleaned up again. The Haskell garbage collector can't do this for you my itself, but you can hook into it by using a [`ForeignPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#t:ForeignPtr) instead of a raw `Ptr`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes     #-}

import Language.C.Inline as C
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.Storable

C.include "<stdio.h>"
C.include "<stdlib.h>"

cArray :: IO (ForeignPtr (Ptr CDouble))
cArray = do
 x <- [C.block| double** {
   int n = 2, m = 2;
   double* arr = malloc(sizeof(double[n*m]));
   double** ptd = malloc(sizeof(double*[n]));
   for (int i=0; i<2; ++i)
     ptd[i] = &(arr[i*m]);
   ptd[0][0] = 1.78;
   ptd[0][1] = 1.68;
   ptd[1][0] = 1.58;
   ptd[1][1] = 1.48;
   printf("the firstelement is: %f\n", ptd[0][0]);
   return ptd;
  }|]
 let finalizer = [C.funPtr| void free2Darray(double** ptd) {
   free(ptd[0]);
   free(ptd);
  }|]
 newForeignPtr finalizer x


main = do
  cArray >>= (`withForeignPtr` \e -> do
    e1 <- peekElemOff e 0
    e2 <- peekElemOff e1 0
    print e2
   )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Btw: Do you know if the memory allocated in C will be cleaned up by Haskell? Or it'll be cleaned up by the operating system when the Haskell program terminates?

Comment: GHC will not `free` any memory you `malloc` while the program is running - how could it know it needs to? Of course, when the program terminates, all memory it uses will be returned to the OS.

Comment: @McBearHolden unless you're ok with some seriously bad karma, you need to clean up the memory yourself. It's C after all! — I should add some explanation on that.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, thx again. BTW2: is the allocated memory safe? I mean will other threads or processes overwrite it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout thx, I was just wondering how to use `ForeignPtr`

Comment: @McBearHolden “Overwrite”? Nah. But I'm not sure if we can consider it completely thread-safe, depending on what's meant by that. But that's rather veering off the topic of the original question.